# x86-64 Load Effective Address Assembly code Reverse Engineering

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

I am trying to reverse engineer some assembly code into C.  I have the following bit of assembly code that I am trying to decipher:

```
lea 0x1(%rbx), %eax
add 0x0(%rbp, %rbx, 4), %eax
cmp %eax, 0x4(%rbp, %rbx,4)
```

And my interpretation line by line is as follows:

- %eax = %rbx + 1
- %eax = %rbp + 4*%rbx + 0
- Compare %eax to %rbp + 4*%rbx + 4

I know that the first three of six iterations yield 1, 2, 4 respectively, but I can't figure out what formula is yielding those values.  Can someone please tell me how I went wrong in deciphering this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to see that the second and third line contain memory accesses. And result depends on the values that are stored there.

The code could be roughly translated to C by the following

```
unsigned char *rbp;

eax = ebx + 1 
eax += *(rbp + rbx*4)
if (eax  XXX *(rbp + rbx*4 + 4) ) ... (with XXX the comparison operator, depends 
                                    on the jmp instruction after the cmp)
```

or if you want to consider rbp a long array (which makes sense from the assembly)

```
unsigned long *rbp;

eax = ebx + 1; 
eax += rbp[rbx];
if (eax  XXX rbp[rbx+1] ) ...   (with XXX the comparison operator, depends
                              on the jmp instruction after the cmp)
```